# How to send notifications without a plugin when a post is updated in WordPress?

Tags: notifications

I have a WordPress website which is not connected to Internet (It's an **Intranet** Site). And i want to send notification emails to some specific email addresses when a specific post is updated.

Is there any way to send the notifications via email, SMS or is there anything i can set in their browsers?